# ASP.Net vnext 1.0.0-rc1-update1 Azure website deployment with Microsoft Release / VSTS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure, ms-release-management

It appears the documentation currently to use Microsoft Release (in preview at the moment) with Visual Studio Team Services (VS Online), is a bit out of date.  I'm simply unable to figure out how to deploy an asp.net vnext website to azure.

Azure is all setup, and I can deploy directly through visual studio itself.  I've followed all the instructions out there, eg [Deploying apps to Azure using Microsoft Release Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/release/getting-started/deploy-to-azure), but this appears to be before update1. For eg all references talk about a single "publish build artifacts" task in the build, whereas now there is an additional "Copy Files".

My problem is I simply can't get the release to deploy.  It always errors with:

> No files were found to deploy with search pattern

It does appear that the website hasn't been published; if I attempt to see the published package via the artifacts link, the website (wwwroot) isn't there (in my solution, only MB.Common which is a portable dll shows [below]).

[image]

I've also added in the msbuild arguments on the build itself to match what I've seen on some tutorials:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:OutDir=$(build.stagingdirectory) /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true  /p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingdirectory)"
```

As well as attempt to set the MS Release "Web Deployment Package" argument on the "Azure Web App Deployment" task to be:

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/MB-Master/drop
```

rather then the default "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.zip"

I really have no idea what the package should look like, and how this should be created now, as I'm sure the examples aren't working anymore.  I'm fairly sure the problem is in the build, and I need to change it to publish the website somehow.